# Does the last line of command in bash shell script carries the exit code to the parent?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script below which is basically do something and calls `diff` at the end.  I would like to know whether bash handles the exit code the same behavior as `diff` does.  Since this script is called by another script, so I would like to know if I need to do any type of error handling to handle the exit code of `diff` then exit ?

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is test.sh

# do something

# last line of the file: 
diff -r $RUN_DIR/testdata/actual_result $RUN_DIR/testdata/expected_result
```

This is another script that calls the above:

```
# this is run_test.sh
if /bin/bash "${dir}/test.sh"; then
  echo "SUCCESS: ${dir}"
else
  echo "FAILED: ${dir}"
  # do not exit here, we continue with other unit tests
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that `diff` command is the last thing executed in that bash file then yes, its return value will be the return value of the bash script.

The alternative is to return an explicit return value by means of the `exit` command, e.g. `exit 113`. The execution will always be terminated after an `exit` call, so you have a bit more flexibility that way...

To find out about such things it is a very good idea to start reading the "man pages": `man bash`...

Comment: Your first sentence is exactly how I wanted. Thanks, sorry I couldn't find much about that on the man page.

Comment: In the `ARGUMENTS` section: "Bash's exit status is the exit status of the last command
       executed in the script."

Comment: @xbeta yes, the bash man page is really too huge to swallow or even find things if you don't know what it is called.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the bash command `help -m exit`:

```
NAME
    exit - Exit the shell.

SYNOPSIS
    exit [n]

DESCRIPTION
    Exit the shell.

    Exits the shell with a status of N.  If N is omitted, the exit status
    is that of the last command executed.

SEE ALSO
    bash(1)

IMPLEMENTATION
    GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

If you would like to make doubly sure, you can use this command after the `diff` line:
`exit $?`

`$?` is a special variable in `bash`. It contains the exit value of the last command executed.